# Magento API to use to integrate ERP System

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, bulk

An ERP company asks you for recommendations which Magento API to use to integrate a client
It is expected that at times large amount of product and category changes will need to be pushed from the ERP to Magento.

**What is the appropriate Magento API for this?**

> 1)The GraphQL API
>
> 2)The synchronous REST API
>
> 3)The asynchronous bulk API
>
> 4)The synchronous bulk API

Answer (score 0):

According to latest and in feature,

> 1)The GraphQL API

This is the best options.

Comment: Why not asynchronous bulk API ?